# How to check string existance in string arraylist in flutter?

Tags: arrays, string, flutter

```
RxList<String> selectedMemberList = <String>[].obs;
selectedMemberList = [180,160,150]
```

I want to display text in red color if ID contains in selectedMemberList.

So, I simply called,

```
if selectedMemberList.contains('180'){
text in red color
}else{
text in black color}
```

but, I got text in black color every time. That means ID doesnt matched.
How do I match member ID to given selectedMemberList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your items are in a single string separated by a comma, first convert that into a list like this :

```
String collectedIds = "180,160,150";
final split = tagName.split(',');
final Map<int, String>  selectedMemberList= {
  for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    i: split[i]
};
```

and now you can check the condition :

```
if selectedMemberList.contains('180'){
text in red color
}else{
text in black color}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: String collectedIds = 180,160,150;

selectedMemberList.add(collectedIds);

So, Problem is here, comma separated strings are not converting in list as an Item.
here is total 3 IDs in string when i converting in list, selectedMemberList length is only one instead of 3. can you help me in conversion of string to stringlist ?

Comment: I did this way. an it is solved

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way on checking if value exist on a list.

```
RxList<String> selectedMemberList = <String>[].obs;
selectedMemberList = ["160","180","150"];
  
  
if (selectedMemberList.where((item) => item == "180").isNotEmpty){
  text in red color
} else {
  text in black color
}
```